# Developing JavaScript APIs by using Third-Party Librarys

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, json-rpc

I currently want to make my project accessible not only via back-end code (C#, Python, PHP, etc.), so I decided to write an easy and simple JS API, every developer can easily integrate within their website / project.
Since the whole thing is a service driven system, most of the stuff runs via RPC encoded as JSON.

My problem is, that if I want to make this API I got the following two options:

1. Writting raw RPC functions from ground up
2. Using jQuery as third-party library

The big problem with option number 2, which is by far the best option, is that I have to say "dear developer, you need to use jQuery to access my API", which is striking me, since I do not want to dictate what ppl should or should not use by restricting their opportunities.

Is there a way implementing jQuery's RPC stuff without breaking any other potential JS framework the final developer will use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're worried about the conflict between jquery and other libraries, use `jQuery.noConflict()` and it solves your problem!
more info at : http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries